# Detecting multiple keyboard presses, How to fix this typescript issue Binding element 'key' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to detect when a user presses multiple keyboard keys simultaneously using typescript, but I keep getting this error

```
Binding element 'key' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
var key: any
```

what type can be used for key in order to remove this error ?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useMultiKeyboardPress() {
  const [keysPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(new Set([]));

  function downListenerHandler({ key }) {
    setKeyPressed(keysPressed.add(key));
  }

  const upListenerHandler = ({ key }) => {
    keysPressed.delete(key);
    setKeyPressed(keysPressed);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", downListenerHandler);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", upListenerHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", downListenerHandler);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", upListenerHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return keysPressed;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript (and therefore Typescript), the `keydown` and `keyup` events pass a [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) to their listeners. So to fix the error you're getting, you just need to specify `KeyboardEvent` as the param type for your handler functions:

```js
  function downListenerHandler({ key }: KeyboardEvent) {
    setKeyPressed(keysPressed.add(key));
  }

  const upListenerHandler = ({ key }: KeyboardEvent) => {
    keysPressed.delete(key);
    setKeyPressed(keysPressed);
  };
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't mention that but I already tried that. the error gets fixed but then I get a new error in the next line for key ```setKeyPressed(keysPressed.add(key));``` 
the error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)

Comment: oh I think I found a solution for the new error 
 ```const [keysPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(new Set<String>([]));```
the ```<String>``` was missing in my initialization of the new Set([])